# Language-specific TypoScript settings in TYPO3 since v9

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

> Used to older TYPO3 versions? The following TypoScript settings will be set based on config.yaml - you don’t need to have them in your TypoScript template:

```
config.language
config.locale_all
config.htmlTag_dir
config.htmlTag_langKey
config.sys_language_uid
config.sys_language_mode
config.sys_language_isocode
config.sys_language_isocode_default
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html

What exactly does that mean? E.g. will the settings from config.yaml always be used? Is it still possible to override them with TypoScript? Should you consider the TypoScript settings as "internal" - written only be TYPO3 using the settings from config.yaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik the TS-Settings are only respected if there is no Site available. So you can think of them more like a fallback. In V10 they will not work anymore so its highly recommended to use Sites only and remove the TS settings.